# What kind of Entropy is considered here for a single bosonic Oscillator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, entropy

In thermofield dynamics, which constitutes an algebraic formulation of thermal quantum field theory, an entropy operator $\hat{S}_\beta$ for a single bosonic oscillator is introduced as

$$\hat{S}_\beta=-k_B\,(\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a}\,\ln\,\sinh^2\theta_\beta-(\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a} +1)\,\ln\cosh^2\theta_\beta)$$

with the Bose-Einstein distribution $\sinh^2\theta_\beta=\langle \hat{n}\rangle_\beta$ ($\hat{n}=\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a}$) and the single-oscillator partition function $\cosh^2\theta_\beta=Z_\beta$. The entropy is obtained as expectation value with respect to the thermal vacuum state $\vert 0_\beta\rangle$ as

$$S_\beta
=
\langle 0_\beta \vert \hat{S}_\beta\vert 0_\beta\rangle
=
-k_B\,(\langle \hat{n}\rangle_\beta \ln \langle \hat{n}\rangle_\beta -(\langle \hat{n}\rangle_\beta+1)\ln Z_\beta).
$$

**To which type of entropy does the latter expression acutally refer to?** I am used to von Neumann entropy as employed in open quantum systems theory, but when I derive von Neumann entropy for a single bosonic (harmonic oscillator) in a canonical thermal equilibrium state, I obtain

$$S_\beta=k_B\,\beta\,\langle \hat{H}\rangle_\beta+k_B\,\ln Z_\beta$$

with $\hat{H}=\omega(\hat{n}+1/2)$ for a single oscillator.

To make things even more puzzling for me, in Celeghini et al., Ann. Phys. 215, 156, (1992), it was shown, that

$$S_\beta
=
\langle 0_\beta \vert \hat{S}_\beta\vert 0_\beta\rangle
=
-k_B \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} W_n\ln W_n
$$

with $W_n=\dfrac{\sinh^{2n}\theta_\beta}{\cosh^{2(n+1)}\theta_\beta}$, which seems to be formally identical to von Neumann entropy. The coefficients $W_n$ are directly obtained by using

$$\vert 0_\beta\rangle = \exp(-\frac{1}{2}\hat{S}_\beta)\sum_{n}\vert n,\tilde{n}\rangle$$

to evaluate the expectation value $\langle 0_\beta \vert \hat{S}_\beta\vert 0_\beta\rangle
$. However, the coefficients $W_n$ seem not to refer to the standard Boltzmann weights of a harmonic oscillators, or at least I was not able to show their equivalence.

**EDIT**

The normalized thermal vacuum state $\vert 0_\beta\rangle$ in TFD is generally defined as

$$\vert 0_\beta \rangle = \dfrac{e^{-\beta\hat{H}/2}}{\sqrt{Z_\beta}}\,\sum_n\,\vert n,\tilde{n}\rangle$$

where I consider $\hat{H}$ as given above for a single bosonic oscillator.

Comment: If you simplify a bit, you can show that all the expressions of entropy are identical. So it is likely that entropy operator is defined in Thermofield dynamics to reproduce Von Neumann entropy when average is computed.

Comment: What do you mean by simplify a bit? I am not quite sure, what to simplify here. As I wrote above, the expression formula Nr. 4 only looks like the von Neumann entropy, however, it does not reproduce the result I obtain without invoking TFD (given by the equation Nr. 3). Therefore it seems not to reproduce von Neumann entropy or I am simply missing something here.

Comment: I meant thay you should use explicit expressions for $\langle \hat{n}\rangle_{\beta}^{}$, $Z_{\beta}^{}$, $\sinh^{2}_{}\theta_{\beta}^{}$ and $\cosh^{2}_{}\theta_{\beta}^{}$ to simplify. Also you should use trigonometric identities for simplification. Let me know, if you want this to be written explicitly as an answer, I can do it soon. And its a good idea to number your equations to refer to them easily.

Comment: Did you mean $|0_\beta\rangle$, the thermal vaccum including the unitary operator in Thermofield dynamics?

Comment: If you can do it quickly, I would appreciate an explicit answer, because I am not completely able to follow your arguments. I edited my post and added the usual definition of the vacuum state in TFD.